# C# WPF - Error when trying to create files on app start-up

Tags: c#, wpf, startup

I am new to Visual Studios, I am trying to make an app that create an .ahk file. My problem is that when the app starts up I need it to create several files/folders. to do this I added this code

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 6)
    {
        string comp_name = System.Environment.UserName;
        System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\" + comp_name + @"\Documents\KeyBind\" + i + @"\Modifier.txt");
        System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\" + comp_name + @"\Documents\KeyBind\" + i + @"\Key.txt");
        System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\" + comp_name + @"\Documents\KeyBind\" + i + @"\Me_Do.txt");
        System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\" + comp_name + @"\Documents\KeyBind\" + i + @"\Text.txt");
        System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\" + comp_name + @"\Documents\KeyBind\" + i + @"\Bind" + i + @".txt");
        System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\Users\" + comp_name + @"\Documents\KeyBind\Bind.ahk");
        i++;
    }
}
```

this results in the following error

```
> An unhandled exception of type
> 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
> PresentationFramework.dll
> 
> Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type
> 'WpfApplication2.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding
> constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position
> '9'.
```

Not sure what the issue is here. 
if you want to look at the full code i have here is the link [Full Code](http://pastebin.com/WZc1qt2M)
I know there is alot of redundant code I plan to fix it, once i figure this out. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: put a try/catch around the code you have in the constructor, then add the information on that exception to your question. Without that exception information it is difficult to say what the problem is.

Comment: Your error is in the xaml, not in the posted code.

Comment: xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"   - This is Line 3 from the .xaml

Comment: You need the exception and the XAML

Comment: Note that `public MainWindow()` is called when your app main window opens and not “when the app starts up ”. Is that a problem?

Comment: Dour High Arch - I jsut need it to create these files when app starts, If I am doing it wrong or there is a better way to do this please tell me.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/p041XV57  -.xaml

Answer (score 0):

Try not using hard-coded Documents paths, and don't try to create directories that already exist.  You also may not want to create the files unless they're missing.

```
private void EnsureFiles()
{
    var numberedFiles = new[] { "Modifier.txt", "Key.txt", "Me_Do.txt", "Text.txt" };

    var basePath = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
        "KeyBind");

    if (!Directory.Exists(basePath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);

    var bindAhkPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Bind.ahk");

    if (!File.Exists(bindAhkPath))
        File.CreateText(bindAhkPath).Dispose();

    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        foreach (var file in numberedFiles)
        {
            var numberedPath = Path.Combine(basePath, i.ToString());

            if (!Directory.Exists(numberedPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(numberedPath);

            var filePath = Path.Combine(numberedPath, file);

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                File.CreateText(filePath).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

As others have suggested, you may want to move this method out of your main window and into your `App` class, then override `OnStartup` to call it.